# how to install panda using easy_install?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am using python 2.7.8 in windows 8 and on cmd I wrote easy_install pandas. After some processing it gave me an error and asked me to download vcpython27.

on cmd:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>easy_install.exe pandas
Searching for pandas
Best match: pandas 0.16.2
Processing pandas-0.16.2-py2.7-win32.egg
pandas 0.16.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.16.2-py2.7-win32.egg
Processing dependencies for pandas
Searching for numpy>=1.7.0
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/
Best match: numpy 1.9.2
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.9.2.zip#md5=
e80c19d2fb25af576460bb7dac31c59a
Processing numpy-1.9.2.zip
Writing c:\users\dell\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-ifrvr4\numpy-1.9.2\setup.c
fg
Running numpy-1.9.2\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\dell\appdata\local
\temp\easy_install-ifrvr4\numpy-1.9.2\egg-dist-tmp-1tqap5
Running from numpy source directory.
non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
non-existing path in 'numpy\\f2py': 'docs'
non-existing path in 'numpy\\f2py': 'f2py.1'
c:\users\dell\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-ifrvr4\numpy-1.9.2\numpy\distutils
\system_info.py:1603: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\users\dell\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-ifrvr4\numpy-1.9.2\numpy\distutils
\system_info.py:1612: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\users\dell\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-ifrvr4\numpy-1.9.2\numpy\distutils
\system_info.py:1615: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
non-existing path in 'numpy\\lib': 'benchmarks'
c:\users\dell\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-ifrvr4\numpy-1.9.2\numpy\distutils
\system_info.py:1505: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\users\dell\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-ifrvr4\numpy-1.9.2\numpy\distutils
\system_info.py:1516: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\users\dell\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-ifrvr4\numpy-1.9.2\numpy\distutils
\system_info.py:1519: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
**error: Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Una
ble to find vcvarsall.bat). Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27**
```

But after I installed "vcpython27" it gave me :

on cmd:

```
n function _main
_configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
_configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _atanhl referenced i
n function _main
_configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
_configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _hypotl referenced i
n function _main
_configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
_configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _atan2l referenced i
n function _main
_configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
_configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _powl referenced in
function _main
_configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
_configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _fmodl referenced in
 function _main
_configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
_configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _modfl referenced in
 function _main
_configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
_configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _frexpl referenced i
n function _main
_configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
_configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ldexpl referenced i
n function _main
_configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
_configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _exp2l referenced in
 function _main
_configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
_configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _log2l referenced in
 function _main
_configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
_configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _copysignl reference
d in function _main
_configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
_configtest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _nextafterl referenc
ed in function _main
_configtest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
_configtest.c
_configtest.c(8) : error C2065: 'HAVE_DECL_SIGNBIT' : undeclared identifier
_configtest.c
_configtest.c(8) : error C2065: 'HAVE_DECL_ISFINITE' : undeclared identifier
_configtest.c
_configtest.c(8) : error C2065: 'signbit' : undeclared identifier
_configtest.c
_configtest.c(8) : error C2065: 'isfinite' : undeclared identifier
_configtest.c
_configtest.c(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'complex.h': No
such file or directory
BUILD_ARCHITECTURE: 'Intel', os.name='nt', sys.platform='win32'
_configtest.c
_configtest.c(3) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
_configtest.c(4) : error C2085: 'static_func' : not in formal parameter list
_configtest.c(4) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
_configtest.c(7) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
_configtest.c(8) : error C2085: 'nostatic_func' : not in formal parameter list
_configtest.c(8) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
_configtest.c
_configtest.c(3) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow '__inline__'
_configtest.c(4) : error C2085: 'static_func' : not in formal parameter list
_configtest.c(4) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
_configtest.c(7) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow '__inline__'
_configtest.c(8) : error C2085: 'nostatic_func' : not in formal parameter list
_configtest.c(8) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
_configtest.c
_configtest.c(7) : error C2065: 'Py_UNICODE_WIDE' : undeclared identifier
File: build\src.win32-2.7\numpy\core\include/numpy\config.h
#define SIZEOF_PY_INTPTR_T 4
#define SIZEOF_OFF_T 4
#define SIZEOF_PY_LONG_LONG 8
#define MATHLIB
#define HAVE_SIN 1
#define HAVE_COS 1
#define HAVE_TAN 1
#define HAVE_SINH 1
#define HAVE_COSH 1
#define HAVE_TANH 1
#define HAVE_FABS 1
#define HAVE_FLOOR 1
#define HAVE_CEIL 1
#define HAVE_SQRT 1
#define HAVE_LOG10 1
#define HAVE_LOG 1
#define HAVE_EXP 1
#define HAVE_ASIN 1
#define HAVE_ACOS 1
#define HAVE_ATAN 1
#define HAVE_FMOD 1
#define HAVE_MODF 1
#define HAVE_FREXP 1
#define HAVE_LDEXP 1
#define HAVE_ATAN2 1
#define HAVE_POW 1
#define HAVE_XMMINTRIN_H 1
#define HAVE_EMMINTRIN_H 1
#define HAVE__MM_LOAD_PS 1
#define HAVE__MM_LOAD_PD 1
#define HAVE___DECLSPEC_THREAD_ 1
#define __NPY_PRIVATE_NO_SIGNAL
#define FORCE_NO_LONG_DOUBLE_FORMATTING
#define ENABLE_SEPARATE_COMPILATION 1
#define HAVE_LDOUBLE_IEEE_DOUBLE_LE 1
#ifndef __cplusplus
#define inline __inline
#endif

#ifndef _NPY_NPY_CONFIG_H_
#error config.h should never be included directly, include npy_config.h instead
#endif

EOF
_configtest.c
_configtest.c(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'inttypes.h': No
 such file or directory
_configtest.c
_configtest.c(6) : fatal error C1189: #error :  gcc >= 4 required
File: build\src.win32-2.7\numpy\core\include/numpy\_numpyconfig.h
#define NPY_SIZEOF_SHORT SIZEOF_SHORT
#define NPY_SIZEOF_INT SIZEOF_INT
#define NPY_SIZEOF_LONG SIZEOF_LONG
#define NPY_SIZEOF_FLOAT 4
#define NPY_SIZEOF_COMPLEX_FLOAT 8
#define NPY_SIZEOF_DOUBLE 8
#define NPY_SIZEOF_COMPLEX_DOUBLE 16
#define NPY_SIZEOF_LONGDOUBLE 8
#define NPY_SIZEOF_COMPLEX_LONGDOUBLE 16
#define NPY_SIZEOF_PY_INTPTR_T 4
#define NPY_SIZEOF_OFF_T 4
#define NPY_SIZEOF_PY_LONG_LONG 8
#define NPY_SIZEOF_LONGLONG 8
#define NPY_NO_SIGNAL 1
#define NPY_NO_SMP 0
#define NPY_HAVE_DECL_ISNAN
#define NPY_HAVE_DECL_ISINF
#define NPY_ENABLE_SEPARATE_COMPILATION 1
#define NPY_VISIBILITY_HIDDEN
#define NPY_ABI_VERSION 0x01000009
#define NPY_API_VERSION 0x00000009

#ifndef __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS 1
#endif

EOF
```

which is totally not understandable. Any idea for solving this issue?

Comment: Do you have numpy installed? The reason I am asking is because the error messages says you do not have, amongst other things, BLAS and LAPACK (which I believe is linear algebra libraries for C, Fortran); all of which necessary in order to use numpy. Have you checked out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641199/how-to-install-numpy-and-pandas-on-windows)?

Comment: no i did nt installed numpy.

Comment: but with easy_install it stll gives me same errors

Comment: I am not a Windows user, so I am not sure how to proceed. However, numpy is a very common dependency so making sure you have that installed is 1.st priority. Reading the numpy [web-site](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/install.html) they recommend python wia something called [enthought](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/) as this includes NumPy. Otherwise download the installer from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/). **Note** Atlas, Lapack are not strictly necessary and can take hours to compile I'd recommend installing the python version including numpy...

Comment: It is not really recommended to compile pandas (or numpy) from source on Windows, unless you want to have a development setup. You should install a precompiled binary: or a wheel from PyPI using pip instead of easy_install (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas), or using a python distribution that includes pandas (eg Anaconda or Canopy)

Comment: i have downloaded pandas-0.16.2-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl (md5) but i dont know what is ".whl" is it compressed zip? like tar.gz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pandas (and various other python libraries) use C things to perform some heavy lifting. Pip packages usually download and compile the C source on the client, and on *nix machines this is fine as they usually have a compiler. Windows, however, doesn't ship with a compiler default. So your options are (from hardest to easiest):

1. Install a C compiler (annoying if you don't otherwise do any C)
2. Install a python distribution like anaconda or enthought which take care of these things for you (these are nice and easy, but you might already have a customised env you want to hold on to).
3. Install the package(s) using a *wheel* - these are the successor to eggs, which don't require compiling on windows. Some packages already ship with wheels, but not all of them. There is, however, the unofficial wheel collection at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ You can download the wheel, and install it using pip.

EDIT: as suggested by @cel - *for god's sake don't use `easy_install`!* Use `pip` instead - many of the packages you need already have wheel packages that pip will find. If you haven't got pip, then try `easy_install pip` (just like the only reason to use Internet Explorer is to use it to download another browser ;)

Comment: so u mean i shall embed it with Microsoft visual compiler? like this http://www.taywils.me/2012/12/23/pythonfinance1.html ?

Comment: This is a nice answer - Although, I think the main point should be: `For god's sake, please don't use easy_install!` :)

Comment: @user3440716 in the blog post you link to, they don't install a compiler (only Visual Studio as IDE), but install everything from precompiled binaries (like step 3 in this post). So better to just skip 1. and choose one of 2. or 3.

Comment: This issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13870 references the same problem - `pip install pandas` is recommended