# Python 3.6 installing pandas Error - No Matching distribution found for pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have tried this out with xlwings too and I get the same error.
I am fairly new to Python. However, I have install other packages such as cx_Oracle with no issues using the same command line as the image. I've tried a lot of different solutions through sites like this but none have worked so far.

I would be grateful for any suggestions as this one I am struggling with!
I forgot to mention my Python is 32 bit.
[image: I've attached an error screenshot of the issue I am having in command prompt]

Comment: Assuming your python is added to PATH, in your cmd, have you tried just running pip install pandas ? (Not from within python within CMD)

Comment: Try `python -m pip install pandas` (or `python3 -m pip install pandas`)

Comment: I have tried this in the C directory in cmd pmt instead of the python directory and I still get the same error. Also my path in env var is ;C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts;%PY_HOME%;%PY_HOME%\LIB;%PY_HOME%\DLLS;%PY_HOME%\LIB\LIB-TK;  - for python related paths.

Comment: Thanks Elazar, I've tried both and still neither work. The python one I get the same error as before. And the python3 cmd i get the error "not recognized as an internal or external command..."

Comment: Answer: need to install other packages before installing pandas. I am going to install Anaconda now as it seems that it may be easier for me as a beginner and wanting to use it for data handling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641199/how-to-install-numpy-and-pandas-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

Giving credits to the answer to a similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68750409/18310090) and other answers here, if you have a python (<=3.6), you need to first update your python, set the latest python as default, and then use
"python -m pip install [package]".

Answer (score -1):

It worked fine for me:

```
> python -m pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a1/3d/d8fece11f6dc9bd332bda6f412be68cf3d505dde280d34e4465d7b71b63c/pandas-0.23.3-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl (6.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 6.6MB 1.2MB/s
Collecting pytz>=2011k (from pandas)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/30/4e/27c34b62430286c6d59177a0842ed90dc789ce5d1ed740887653b898779a/pytz-2018.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 512kB 1.2MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.0 in c:\users\hoss\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.14.5)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.5.0 (from pandas)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/f5/af2b09c957ace60dcfac112b669c45c8c97e32f94aa8b56da4c6d1682825/python_dateutil-2.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (211kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 215kB 1.5MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\hoss\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas) (1.11.0)
Installing collected packages: pytz, python-dateutil, pandas
Successfully installed pandas-0.23.3 python-dateutil-2.7.3 pytz-2018.5
```