# No matching distribution found for pandas==1.3.1

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have Pandas with version 1.1.5 and I am trying to install the newest version of Pandas by using the following command

```
$ pip install pandas==1.3.1
```

However, I get an error as follows:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas==1.3.1 (from versions: 0.1, 0.2b0, 0.2b1, 0.2, 0.3.0b0, 0.3.0b2, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.8.0rc1, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.2, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 0.19.2, 0.20.0, 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.3, 0.21.0, 0.21.1, 0.22.0, 0.23.0, 0.23.1, 0.23.2, 0.23.3, 0.23.4, 0.24.0, 0.24.1, 0.24.2, 0.25.0, 0.25.1, 0.25.2, 0.25.3, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas==1.3.1
```

I am using Python 3.6.8
How can I solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Pandas dropped support for Python 3.6 in version 1.2.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.2.0.html#increased-minimum-version-for-python) (December, 2020).

Either upgrade to Python 3.7+ or make do with [Pandas 1.1.5](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/1.1.5/), which is the last version to support Python 3.6.