# Amazon Sagemaker JupiterLab Notebook - No matching distribution found for Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, pip, jupyter-lab, amazon-sagemaker

If I attempt to Upgrade **Pandas** above version **1.1.5** on my **AWS Sagemaker** provided **JupyterLab** notebook I receive the error **No Matching Distribution Found**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this - [No matching distribution found for pandas==1.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68750375/no-matching-distribution-found-for-pandas-1-3-1)

The latest version to support python 3.6 is 1.1.5.

You can create a new conda environment with python version >= 3.7 in your existing notebook, or move to notebooks with Amazon Linux 2 (see [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-now-supports-amazon-linux-2/)). In the AL2 notebooks, `conda_python3` kernels come with Python 3.8.